# Há muito a considerar. --- Haver vs Ter

Tags: verbos

what is the rule for when you use ter versus haver for "there is".

- `Há muito a considerar` - there is much to consider
- `Há manteiga na geladeira/frigorífico?` - is there butter in the fridge?

but

- `Tem muitos brasileiros aqui.` - there are many Brazilians here.
- `Tem cinco brigadeiros na geladeira.` - tere are 5 chocolate cupcakes in the fridge

It seems like I can use either. It might be just a mistake in the courseware but I noticed I was flagged wrong for using "Tem" instead of "há" when translating  `there is much to consider`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O uso de *ter* em sentido existencial (como verbo impessoal) não ocorre em português europeu (pelo menos na variedade padrão) e é estigmatizado na norma brasileira, ainda que seja muito frequente na oralidade. É preferível portanto usar o verbo *haver*:

> **Há** muito a/para/que considerar.

Uma alternativa consensual com *ter* terá de ter um sujeito argumental. Por exemplo, com significado semelhante, dependendo do caso, podemos ter:

> **Temos**/**Eles têm** muito a/para/que considerar.

Answer (score 3):

In Portugal all the given examples would use the verb *haver*.

Not being always true, but my rule of thumb to distinguish between those two verbs is existence (haver) versus possession/ownership/inclusiveness (ter).

When something simple exist, we use haver:

Há quem limpe corações.

When someone owns something or something is a component of something else we use ter:

O José tem dois patos.

O carro tem quatro rodas.

An interesting thing to keep in mind is that the subject of the sentence changes the verb, even when sentence mean more or less the same:

Há muita água no balde. - there is a lot of water in the bucket.

Esse balde tem muita água. - that bucket have a lot of water.