# Is it acceptable to substitute "ter" for "haver" or "existir" in formal contexts?

Tags: verbos, coloquialismos

Prescriptivists have often criticized the widespread use of verb “ter” in Brazil, when you really mean “haver” or “existir”.

- Tem gente que não sabe como…
- Tem alguém aí fora
- Tem muito tempo que...
- Tem três anos que eu...
- Tinha uma menina na minha turma que...
- Tem mais estrelas no céu do que...

I’ve never paid attention to this before and cannot recall whether the Portuguese have the same verbal habit. **My question is:**

1.**Is it acceptable in formal writing? For example, when writing a composition for an examination.**

2.**Is one likely to be frowned upon if they say *"tem uma coisa que eu gostaria de dizer a todos os presentes"* at a formal speech?**

3.**Is there any region in Brazil where people rarely use "ter" in such contexts?**

4.**Do people ever use it anywhere in Portugal?**

Edit: An answer to this question can be partially found in [Há muito a considerar. --- Haver vs Ter](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/h%C3%A1-muito-a-considerar-haver-vs-ter)

Comment: Can you explain why you are asking this question in English? Personally, for time, I don't say tem muito tempo que, I say: Faz muito tempo que. I think the two time ones are the only really objectionable ones.

Comment: @Lambie   Fi-lo porque assim o quis.  Não é a primeira vez que o faço e nem é a única pergunta formulada em inglês no PL.

Comment: I can only speak to 4) while such of _ter_ is certainly not unheard of in Portugal, it's not widespread: most people will use only _haver_. _Tem três anos que_ is even rarer, by far the most frequent is _há três anos que_, with _faz três anos que_ a distant second, sounding a bit popular or dated. I'm talking about middle-class Lisbon people here.

Comment: we do say _vai fazer três meses que_, as you cannot express the same idea with _haver_. I'm not sure that's the same of usage of _fazer_ though, I think it just means _completar_ there, as in _ele faz três anos em Janeiro_.

Comment: Expanding on @Artefacto's comment, for me the only one I would expect in portugal is the fifth: "Tinha um traquinas na minha turma que só armava banzé." But *haver* would be more commonly used.

Comment: Tudo bem. Para mim, é meio estranho falar sobre uma língua em outra quando o assunto não é tradução. Acho que poucas pessoas usariam ter com o tempo. Soa "não nativo" em fala cotidiana. Ter se usa para haver e existir, mas que eu saiba, não para fazer, no sentido de faz tempo. Acho que fazer + anos (meses, dias) é idiomático. https://sol.sapo.pt/artigo/654108 [Por favor, podemos usar maíusculas com nomes próprios em inglês?\

Comment: A sample sentence that I personally use a lot: «tem dias...»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a linguist, but I'll try to answer your question from a native speaker's point of view. Also, since I'm not Portuguese, I don't think I'm in a position to answer your fourth question. As for the other three...

To begin with, "tem muito tempo que eu..." and "tem três anos que eu..." don't sound particularly informal. Most of the time, people will use the verb "fazer" in this context ("faz muito tempo que eu...", "faz três anos que eu..."), so using "ter" in these cases is actually sort of uncommon. As for your other examples, "ter" is clearly the informal option, whereas "haver" sounds a lot more formal.

With that in mind, this usage of "ter" with the meaning of "haver" should be avoided in formal writing, and it would seem "off" in a composition. However, in a speech, even a formal one, this does not sound so weird. Of course, this depends on how formal the situation is and on the tone you want to convey. For instance, if you have to deliver a formal speech, but you want to sound accessible or open to the audience, this would probably be OK. In your example, "tem uma coisa que eu gostaria de dizer a todos os presentes" sounds pretty OK if this is to be said in a formal speech at a wedding or a formal dinner, for instance, or maybe if this is a thank-you speech you're thinking of. If you're thinking of a more formal ceremony, maybe you should be a litlle bit more cautious.

As to your third question, as far as I know, this usage of "ter" is widespread in Brazil. I don't think there is any region where this is uncommon.

Comment: Native speaker from Rio de Janeiro.  "Q: quando foi que aconteceu?   A: Ah, isso já tem muito tempo." is quite common here.  Just as common as "faz muito tempo".  "Há" would sound awkward here.

Comment: First you say "it's sort of uncommon". Then "I don't think it's uncommon".

Answer (score 1):

None of those example is used in Portugal. As said in the linked question, the verb *ter* os always used with a subject - that can be omitted - while the sentence don't have a subject, in which case the verb haver should be used.

Comment: Welcome to PL.  Feel free to answer in Portuguese.