# Como substituir “ter” por “haver”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, verbos

Tenho dúvida sobre como substituir ***ter*** por ***haver***, embora já tenha visto [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/h%C3%A1-muito-a-considerar-haver-vs-ter).

Minha dúvida é assim: eu sei que podemos substituir ***ter*** e ***existir*** por ***haver***. Mas por que não conjugamos o verbo ***haver*** depois da substituição? Ou seja:

> Amanhã, temos uma visita de estudos no Instituto Oswaldo Cruz.
>
> Amanhã, há uma visita de estudos no Insituto Oswaldo Cruz.

> Depois da palestra, tivemos um debate.
>
> Depois da palestra, houve um debate.

Por que não dizemos ***havemos***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjugamos sim, se não conjugássemos ficava simplesmente "haver".

Mas conjugamos na terceira pessoa porque a construção é diferente:

> Amanhã, (nós) temos (...)
> Amanhã, (ele*) há (...)

> Depois da palestra, (nós) tivemos um debate.
> Depois da palestra, (ele*) houve um debate.

Em ambos os exemplos o haver é conjugado. Mas a construção da frase com haver tem uma estrutura diferente. O verbo haver é conjugado "**impessoalmente**" — sem sujeito e na terceira pessoa do singular.

Esta página explica isto adequadamente:

http://escreverbem.com.br/como-flexionar-o-verbo-haver-2/

---

Nota: em algumas situações o haver é usado com sujeito, e conjugado, p.e.:

> Havemos de conversar sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

Tanto o verbo ter quanto o verbo haver são tidos como impessoais. Este usado na linguagem formal e aquele na coloquial

Analisemos o seguinte enunciado, no sentido de obtermos respostas a questionamentos relevantes, como este que se faz presente, ou seja, devemos mesmo usar o verbo ter? Ou o ideal é optarmos pelo uso do verbo haver?

Tinham alunos no pátio.

Um termo nos chama a atenção acerca de sua real função em meio ao contexto linguístico: alunos, por excelência.

Retomemos, pois, àquela velha e boa dica no sentido de descobrirmos o sujeito da oração: fazer a pergunta ao verbo. O que tinham? Provavelmente que uma boa parte diria que a resposta correta seria “alunos”.

Nesse caso devemos ter o máximo de cuidado, haja vista que se trata de um verbo impessoal, portanto, sem sujeito. Dessa forma, a função do termo em pauta (alunos) é a de objeto direto, ou seja: Tinha o quê? Alunos.

Mas por que “tinha” e não “tinham”?

Ora, pelo simples fato de que se se trata de uma oração sem sujeito, o verbo, necessariamente, deverá permanecer na terceira pessoa do singular.

Nesse sentido, mesmo que o objeto esteja no plural, ele, o verbo, ficará sempre no singular. Vejamos outros casos:

Tem homens e mulheres concorrendo à vaga.
Tem momentos em que nos sentimos desanimados.
Na cidade tem pessoas de vários ugares.

Em todos os enunciados constatamos que o termo em destaque ocupa a função sintática já mencionada. Outro detalhe a que devemos nos atentar é que o verbo, conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular, não é grafado com o acento circunflexo (pois se assim fosse pertenceria à terceira pessoa do plural - têm).

Agora, situemo-nos mediante o padrão formal da linguagem, e façamos a seguinte pergunta: será que tais colocações a ele se encontram adequadas?

Saiba que em se tratando de situações comunicativas, tidas como formais, tais como a escrita ou até mesmo aquelas manifestadas pela oralidade, como uma entrevista, uma palestra, uma conferência, faz-se necessário o uso do verbo haver. Assim, reformulando, temos:

Há homens e mulheres concorrendo à vaga.
Há momentos em que nos sentimos desanimados.
Na cidade há pessoas de vários ugares.

Perceba que o verbo permanece nas mesmas condições de impessoalidade, ou seja, conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular.

Comment: Limareste, bem-vindo ao site. A tua resposta passa um bocado ao lado da pergunta, que é sobre "temos uma visita de estudos", "tivemos um debate". Isto é um uso pessoal do verbo *ter*, não é o uso impessoal que tu explicas. A tua resposta tem mais que ver com [esta outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/h%C3%A1-muito-a-considerar-haver-vs-ter).

Answer (score 1):

Nos teu exemplos, o verbo *haver* significa ’existir, acontecer’. Vejamos um exemplo mais simples:

> **Há** uma árvore no quintal = **Existe** uma árvore no quintal
>
> **Há** duas árvores no quintal = **Existem** duas árvores no quintal

Nestes exemplos, *árvore(s)* é o sujeito do verbo *existir*. Portanto, *exist**e** uma árvore* (singular), *exist**em** duas árvores* (plural). Mas o verbo *haver*, no sentido de ’existir’, não tem sujeito (*árvore(s*) é complemento direto); como diz o ANeves, é um verbo impessoal. Por isso é sempre conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular: *há, houve, havia*, etc.

No Brasil, coloquialmente, também se diz *tem duas árvores no quintal*. Aqui o verbo *ter* funciona exatamente como o *haver*. É disso que trata [a outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/h%C3%A1-muito-a-considerar-haver-vs-ter) que tu referiste. Mas nos teus exemplos, o verbo *ter* tem um sentido um pouco diferente: *eu **tenho** uma árvore no quintal*, indica que a árvore é minha; não significa simplesmente que a árvore existe. Nos teus exemplos:

> Amanhã, **temos** uma visita de estudos
>
> Amanhã, **há** uma visita de estudos

O *temos* implica ***nós** temos*, e as pessoas vão entender que nós vamos participar na visita de estudos. Já *há uma visita de estudos* significa apenas que se essa visita vai acontecer; não se conclui obrigatoriamente que nós vamos. Seria perfeitamente normal dizer:

> Amanhã, há uma visita de estudos, mas nós — eu e o João — não vamos porque não estamos interessados.

Mas seria um pouco estranho dizer *temos uma visita de estudos, mas nós não vamos*. Do mesmo modo, em *tivemos um debate*, entende-se que nós estivemos no debate; em *houve um debate*, podemos ter estado ou não.